# Minecraft server .jar controlled trough python script using subprocess

Tags: python, server, minecraft

im trying to make a python script that lets me input commands into the minecraft server.
I'm having issues with multiple commands
[image]

I want it to run "say test" "list" "save-all" separately but instead, it just runs "say testlistsave-all"

Comment: Looks like the program does not know where your individual commands end. How about adding a space or a newline (`\n`) at the end of each command string.

Comment: adding a space didnt work but a newline fixed it! Thanks, also i already tried \n but i used /n instead so thats why it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You never write the `ENTER` key.

Do do that, you have to write a newline char `\n` at the end of each command. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36564152/10952503))

So, you will have something like that:

```py
MCser.stdin.write(b'say test\n')
MCser.stdin.write(b'list\n')
MCser.stdin.write(b'save-all\n')
```

You can something like that to run command easier:

```java
def runcmd(mycmd):
   MCser.stdin.write(mycmd)
   MCser.stdin.write(b'\n')

runcmd(b'say test')
runcmd(b'list')
runcmd(b'save-all')
```